# Apache Rewrite only for valid URL

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx, url-rewriting, lighttpd

I have a purely personal website (Apache2 on Ubuntu), and to prvent outsiders from knowing there is a valid HTTP server at the specified domain, it uses  with cryptic URLs.  For example,

> http://somesite.com

will, by design, return HTTP 404 error. But

> http://somesite.com/RJv968sr0S860Iq1VfW2P28dqgCTqNUOm51AMuQL

might do something useful.  I'm sure it is not a full proof method to deter interlopers, bots and hackers, but its there nevertheless.

Now, in addition to obscuring the URLs, I also use HTTPS for further protection, for which I have Apache rewrite HTTP requests to HTTPS.

```
  RewriteEngine ON
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !192\.168\.
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !127\.0\.0\.1
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
  RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

And it works exactly as expected.

Unfortunately, it is not terribly sophisticated, and it also rewrites invalid URL requests. For example, the invalid URL http://somesite.com  will get rewritten to the equally invalid URL https://somesite.com.  But, this kind of rewrite would tip off someone that there is, indeed, some kind of HTTP server attached to the domain name.

I would like to fix my rewrite rules so that Apache will NOT rewrite any invalid URLs.  Is this possible?  If not with Apache, what about nginx or lighttpd?  And if so, how do I make it happen?

Comment: What constitutes a valid URL? Do you have actual existing files at every path (which could be used to test with a `-f` in `RewriteCond`)?  Note that trying to hide the server's presence by obscuring URLs isn't really helpful. To find it, interlopers would more likely scan for the open ports 80,443 on the IP or domain than look for a known URI like `/` or `/index.html`.

Comment: Open 80 and 443 ports would tip anyone that there is http server.

Comment: @Berkowski I guess I'm not fluent in HTTP speak, but I've disabled all standard URI such as / and /index.html.  All existing URIs are random hashes.  I don't what Apache to rewrite the URL unless it points to an existing URI.

Comment: @Ten In terms of open 80 and 443, I understand it is evidence of a existing HTTP server.   I tried to use other ports, but it conflicted with one application, so I'm sticking with 80 and 443 for now.  So I would like to just minimize evidence of life at those ports.